# Code to clear cells with a confirmation message

Tags: excel, vba

Wanting to modify the below to ask.."ARE YOU SURE...ALL USER DATA Will BE CLEARED"

```
Sub emptyUnlocked()
ActiveSheet.Protect
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.UsedRange = ""
On Error GoTo 0
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function

Comment: What happened when you tried that?